# Cover all interface subtypes with one call of IS operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am struggling to find out the best way to fix my problem.
I have some interface **ITokenResolver** and a concrete implementor **ObjectGraph**
and a piece of some code of ObjectGraph class:

```
    bool ITokenResolver.HasCollision(ITokenResolver other, out string msg)
    {
        if (!(other is ObjectGraph og))
        {
             msg = null;
             return false;
        }

        var samePaths = GetAllPaths().Intersect(og.GetAllPaths());
        if (samePaths.Count() > 0)
        {
            msg = $"Both graphs contain same object paths: [{string.Join(StringExtensions.Comma, samePaths)}]";
            return true;
        }

        msg = null;
        return false;
    }
```

What worries me is that user of my library can create almost same implementor behavior (implementor of **ITokenResolver**, but not a **Graph** class). 
My code works perfectly only for my predefined type, but I don't know how to make it better to work for all GRAPH-LIKE resolvers. Should I make a new interface like **IGraphResolver**, so my implementor would be changed to `public class ObjectGraph: ITokenResolver, IGraphResolver`? With a new interface I could cover all specific resolvers without knowing implementation, but relying on interface. Is it correct?
My original code on GitHub: [ObjectGraph.cs](https://github.com/nikolayresh/TextExtensionsNet/blob/master/src/TextExtensionsNet.Library/Tokenization/ObjectGraph.cs)

Comment: The fact that your interface code, relies on the instance being a particular concrete type, makes me think your code is ripe for refactoring. Especially when that interface is exposed publicly in a library. It very much sticks 2 fingers up to the Liskov Substitution principle, which if you aren't familiar with, I'd google it

Comment: OK, thanks. I plan to avoid cast by adding a new method to interface like this one - GetAllTokenKeys() as each token resolver holds them internally. And then they keys of one token resolver will be compared to keys of other resolver and if any intersections appear, then we assume they have collision. Thank, bro